# When comparing files with TFS, only the deleted lines are shown

Tags: tfs

Let's say before I check in, on the team explorer I right click on a file and compare it to workspace/latest version (doesn't really matter which, and the location neither, it's the same thing with code reviews, Changeset details->compare with previous) it will only show the deleted/red lines in the file, although it does show the added (green) parts in the scrollbar.

Have anyone had this problem before? I imagine a reinstall might just work, but I'd like to avoid it, if I can.

Comment: Does this issue occur just on your machine? Or other users' machines as well?

Comment: Only for my machine. And it probably isn't caused by the extensions installed on my PC either, because that would be only autoshelve & productivity power tools.

Comment: You may want to try clearing the cache on your local machine for Visual Studio, sometimes it does some funky things and removing (or moving) the cache can sometimes fix it. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/

Answer (score 0):

If the error is only occurs for your machine. It's more likely related to VS. Usually reinstall vs is the final solution.

You can also try the suggestion as *Sachi* commented, try to [clear TFS and VS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsalm/2013/12/17/how-to-clear-the-tfs-cache-on-client-machines/). This may do the trick.

If it's not work, still suggest you to reinstall VS. Even though this may not be a good solution. After all, it's very likely you have taken a long time to trouble shooting the weird issue and still can't find the root cause.